# How can I find embedded Mongoid documents based on multiple criteria?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a Mongoid document with embedded documents in it. I want to search the top-level documents for all of them where there is an embedded document that has multiple criteria.

```
TopDoc.where('inside.first_name' => 'Bob', 'inside.last_name' => 'Jones')
```

But it seems to me this would match on a TopDoc with Bob Wever and Paul Jones, which is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#_S_elemMatch). With Mongoid, the following line should do the trick

```
TopDoc.elem_match(inside: { first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones' })
```

which is equivalent to :

```
TopDoc.where(:inside.elem_match => { first_name: 'Bob', last_name: 'Jones'})
```